# why does setting a UITableViewCell's color work in "willDisplayCell" but not in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

why does setting a `UITableViewCell`'s color work in `willDisplayCell` but not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Notes:

1. I'm using this code to set the background color of a cell: `[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];`
2. works when I put it in the method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
3. does NOT work if I put in in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Can you post your implementations of `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doco for `UITableViewCell` states that you need to do it in `willDisplayCell:`  (excerpt from the `UITableViewCell` class reference below).  I suspect that because table cells have a content view and various other components that seem to be 'managed' by `UIKit`, that its doing its own thing with the background color after its set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You can also use the 'backgroundView' property of a table view cell to control its background.

documentation excerpt:

*Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the `backgroundColor` property declared by `UIView`) you must do it in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method of the delegate and not in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the data source. Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded rectangle instead of the area outside of it.*

Answer (score 0):

In simple words,`cellForRowAtIndex` will define the behavior of the `UIObject` in cell (like labels, button, view).
(i.e background color, font style, fontcolor).
If you like to change the look of the cell, that can only be done in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

More explanation here: https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/proper-use-of-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willdisplaycell/?gh_src=4n3gxh1